# gRPC client call fails when changing localhost to the server computer name or IP

Tags: c#, .net-core, grpc

I have a gRPC client calling into a server on the same machine and client code uses the channel created with:

```
Channel channel = new Channel("localhost", 11112, ChannelCredentials.Insecure);
```

This works well, and I'm getting the reply as expected.

However, if I replace **"localhost"** with the actual machine name (FQDN) or IP address, I'm getting an error:

```
Status(StatusCode="Unavailable", Detail="failed to connect to all addresses", DebugException="Grpc.Core.Internal.CoreErrorDetailException: {"created":"@1616190440.553000000","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"..\..\..\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\client_channel.cc","file_line":5397,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1616190440.553000000","description":"failed to connect to all addresses","file":"..\..\..\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\lb_policy\pick_first\pick_first.cc","file_line":398,"grpc_status":14}]}")
```

I also tested starting the server on a remote machine and having the client call into that remote machine (by name or IP) when creating the channel, but got the same failure.
The application is written in C# .NET Core 3.2 as a Console application. Nuget packages included are: Google.Protobuf, Grpc.Core, Grpc.Tools.

Not sure what is wrong in my code or whether something is not setup properly on my machine.

Here's the reset of the relevant client code:

```
MWCS.McpsServer.McpsServerClient client = new MWCS.McpsServer.McpsServerClient(channel);
var data = new ProcessResponseInput() { ClientID = clientID };
var options = new CallOptions();
try {
  var res = client.ProcessResponse(data, options);
  return res;
} catch (RpcException ex) {
  StandardOutput so = new StandardOutput() { ExitCode = 1, Message = ex.Message };
  return so;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this, I actually had to fix the server code. I should have used `"0.0.0.0"` instead of `"localhost"` in the bind address on the server. Looks like when setting the server to localhost it is not visible outside the computer.

Here's how I have the server started now (after the replacement):

```
_server = new Server() {
               Services = { McpsServer.BindService(new McpcServerImplementation()) },
               Ports = { new ServerPort("0.0.0.0", 11112, ServerCredentials.Insecure) }
         };
```